# Training a RNN to output word2vec embedding instead of logits

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

Traditionally it seems that RNNs use logits to predict next time step in the sequence. In my case I need the RNN to output a word2vec (50 depth) vector prediction. This means that the cost function has be based off 2 vectors: `Y` the actual vector of the next word in the series and `Y_hat`, the network prediction.

I've tried using a `cosine distance` cost function but the network does not seem to learn (I've let it run other 10 hours on a AWS P3 and the cost is always around 0.7)

Is such a model possible at all ? If so what cost function should be used ?

Cosine distance in TF:

```
cosine_distance = tf.losses.cosine_distance(tf.nn.l2_normalize(outputs, 2), tf.nn.l2_normalize(targets, 2), axis=2)
```

**Update:**
I am trying to predict a word2vec so during sampling I could pick next word based on the closest neighbors of the predicted vector.

Comment: It's hard to say why convergence isn't happening since it can be a function of many hyperparameters. However, one thing strikes me: wouldn't cosine distance where normalization happens inside the loss calculation be ambiguous? There could be infinitely many vectors with the same loss (any rescaling, for example). So maybe during training it is oscillating around a bunch of different scalings for similar vectors, and these keep giving the same loss, so it can't see any difference between them.

Comment: Perhaps add the normalization step as a layer prior to the loss, so the network can only produce normalized vectors, and the gradient will be w.r.t. the normalized values in each component. Otherwise, perhaps try with a different loss, such as mean squared error of the vectorwise difference, and perhaps also add a kernel regularizer to penalize the l2 norm of the predicted vector. At the very least, just to see if convergence properties differ from the cosine distance case. If not, then perhaps look into batch sizes, gradient issues, and other hyperparameters.

Comment: I also was bugged by having only one scalar value for the cost as the "spacial" information of the word2vec would be lost. I've tried using MSE as well but I couldn't manage to make it work. I am gonna try your suggestions and see If I can get MSE to work

Answer (score 5):

What is the reason that you want to predict a word embedding? Where are you getting the "ground truth" word embeddings from? For word2vec models you typically will re-use the trained word-embeddings in future models. If you trained a `word2vec` model with an embedding size of 50, then you would have 50-d embeddings that you could save and use in future models. If you just want to re-create an existing ground truth word2vec model, then you could just use those values. Typical word2vec would be having regular softmax outputs via [continuous-bag-of-words or skip-gram](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-continuous-bag-of-words-and-skip-gram-architectures) and then saving the resulting word embeddings.

If you really do have a reason for trying to generate a model that creates tries to match word2vec, then looking at your loss function here are a few suggestions. I do not believe that you should be normalizing your outputs or your targets -- you probably want those to remain unaffected (the targets are no longer the "ground truth" targets if you have normalized them. Also, it appears you are using `dim=0` which has now been deprecated and replaced with `axis`. Did you try different values for `dim`? This should represent the dimension along which to compute the cosine distance and I think that the `0th` dimension would be the wrong dimension (as this likely should be the batch size. I would try with values of `axis=-1` (last dimension) or `axis=1` and see if you observe any difference.

Separately, what is your optimizer/learning rate? If the learning rate is too small then you may not actually be able to move enough in the right direction.

Comment: One reason why you might want to do this is so that you now have a trained network capable of mapping a previously unseen word into its vector embedding representation. Particularly if you are starting from a character-based model that produces the *word* embedding vector. The target value would be a whole embedding vector for a given matrix of one-hot encoded character values making up the original word. Up to a limit on word size, this would allow you to embed new words not originally in your word2vec dictionary.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question with some background as to why I want the model to output word2vec. For axis, indeed this is the wrong one, the one in the actual code is 2, as my input is in shape (batch size * sequences len * embedding depth ). I've updated the code. The learning rate start at 0.01 and decayed down to 0.00x. 
Also I am using Standfords pretrained GloVe word2vecs

Comment: @silkAdmin it is still unclear to me why learning a traditional word embedding is not sufficient or why you couldn't use GloVe word2vecs in the first place? When are you doing this sampling? Are you saying that you have a sequence of words and you want to predict the next word? The "continuous bag of words" model is a model that tries to predict words given the context of a few words before and a few words after the target word. So in this sense it still seems like you should just train a word embedding using continuous bag of words via softmax. Why does this not work for your task?

Comment: I do use a pre-trainned word2vec. The only difference with your traditional text generating RNN model is that i'd like the network to output a word2vec estimat rather than probabilities. This will allow me during sampling to  search for "closest vectors" in my dictionary instead of using a random function to pick next word.

Comment: That makes sense now -- I assume you are also using `cosine_distance` to select the closest vectors? Now that you have fixed the axis -- are you having better learning? Did you try without learning rate decay? If nothing was being learned (or very little being learned), you would not want to decay the learning rate

Comment: @reese0106 Yes `cosines_distance` is also used to select vectors. The axis was fixed originally (it was only my code example here that had the error). So no the network is still not learning anything..

Comment: @silkAdmin did you try a larger learning rate or different optimizer (like Adam) -- if you're not learning anything there is definitely no need to decay the learning rate. Given so many different words, I would expect the cosine distances to be very close to eachother, so the learning rate may need to be quite large to be able to take any steps.  Just a thought